# ext js file download or JSON process conditionally depending upon MEDIA type

Tags: extjs, jersey, download

I am using Jersey with ext js in front end, I am submitting a form using
`Ext.fly`

```
Ext.fly(form).set({
    id : 'downloadForm',
    target: hiddenIframe,
    method: 'POST',
    action: downldObj.url
});

 form.submit();
```

It works fine with file download popup in browser. But my requirement is when I try to send
conditionally JSON response

```
return Response.status(Status._StatusError).entity("{success:false,result:'failed'}").type("application/json").build();
```

Ext Js cannot identify the JSON. Is there anyway in EXT- JS by which I can process the JSON response or prompt 
download conditionally.

Comment: You're sending an invalid JSON as your entity `{success:false,result:'failed'}` which should be `{"success":false, "result":"failed"}`. Do you see any exception on the server?

Comment: hi Michael thanks for response is there anyway I can conditionally handle either json response from server or application/msexcel according to situation.my requirement is if there is no error at server the user should see file download popup else error message in the front end